# If condition into Gridview Column design

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview. its data source is a datatable that is loaded from the database. In this gridview, i have a template column.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Type" SortExpression="ProductID">
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="MP-table-tb-display-item" />
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div class="MP-table-tb-display-main">
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkview" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' CommandName="Viewproduct"
                                                    runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="lnkview_Click"><h4>
                                        <%# Eval("Name") %>
                                    </h4>
                                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                            </div>
                                            <br />
                                            <div class="MP-table-tb-display">
                                                <p>
                                                    <span>KEY</span><%# Eval("[product_type_key]") %></p>
                                                <br />

                                                <a target="_blank" href='<%# Eval("SourceURL") %>'>Source</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

In this I want Source hyperlink only show when data available into `<%# Eval("SourceURL") %>`. If I am not able to get the SourceURL value into `RowDatabound Event` . Please Guide me.

I plan for this too but this is not working properly.

```
<a target="_blank" href=' <%= Eval("SourceURL")!=null ? Eval("SourceURL") : "style='display: none'" %> />'>  Source</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this instead

```
<asp:hyperlink  Target="_blank"  NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("SourceURL") %>' Visible = '<%# Eval("SourceURL") == null ? false : true %>' >
```

Similarly you could use the `<a>` tag to control its visiblity. The if condition would go in Style attribue and not in href attribute. Something like this

```
Style=display:Eval('some_val') == null ? none : block
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<a target="_blank" href='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("SourceURL").ToString()) ? "" : Eval("SourceURL"))'%> style='display: none'>Source</a>
```

Thanks